# unresolveable build extensions maven nar plugin

Tags: c++, maven

I swear this is a very simple question, but somehow I just cannot figure it out. It's simply a hello world in c++. And i am using nar-maven-plugin.

I've looked into other questions but still the problem is unsolved.

here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>

  <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </properties>
     <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nar-marven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.1</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                           <os>Linux</os>
                           <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                           <cpp>
                            <name>g++</name>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <options>
                                <option>-g</option>
                                <option>-Wall</option>
                            </options>
                           </cpp>
                           <linker>
                             <name>g++</name>
                           </linker>
                           <libraries>
                                <library>
                                    <type>executable</type>
                                </library>
                           </libraries>
                       </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cppunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>cppunit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've downloaded one example application of nar maven plugin, and it worked well. But with my own application it cannot.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:jar:3.5.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:jar:3.5.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: nar @ line 6, column 14
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for cppunit:cppunit:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project myapp:myapp:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/liu/Downloads/mavenproj/myapp/pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:jar:3.5.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: nar @ line 6, column 14
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for cppunit:cppunit:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

thanks a lot ahead!

Comment: The problem is before running it: `[WARNING] The POM for com.github.maven-nar:nar-marven-plugin:jar:3.5.1 is missing, no dependency information available` the download does not work..Network / Firewall / Proxy issues...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thanks for your reply..but I dont think so. Because in another project the com.github.maven-nar worked very well. I cannot be problem of network..

Comment: If you have messages of missing jars in your output than there is something wrong which causes issues...In the output before there had been WARNINGs somewhere ...etc. please add the full output of a build on command line `mvn clean package `..

Comment: Hi Khmarbaise, I've found the failure...I wrote the artifactId wrongly...instead of maven I wrote marven.... :))